# Cheap storage lockers in Tromsø, Norway

Tags: norway, luggage-storage, tromso

I'm going on a two week hiking trip around Tromsø in Norway and I like to have a fresh set of clothes for the flight back so I don't bother anybody (including myself) with my body odor on the airplane.

Because I have to carry literally everything I use on my back for two weeks I would prefer to store my airplane clothes somewhere in Tromsø.

The airport does offer [baggage storage](https://avinor.no/en/airport/tromso-airport/plan-your-trip/check-in-and-baggage/baggage-storage/) for 60NOK (≈6€/6.7$) per day, which projected for the 14 days is quite a sum.

In Germany there are storage lockers at train stations for about 2€/72hours so I wanted to ask if there is anything similar in Norway/Tromsø.

The size of the stored clothes would be a small plastic bag and no suitcase.

Comment: Have you considered alternatives, like buying a new set of (cheap) clothes for the flight back or washing them at a laundromat before you leave?

Comment: @Gremlin  Just buying a set of clothes is too wasteful for me and a laundromat wouldn't be an option as all my hiking gear is merino wool which I can't put into a dryer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are spending any night in a hotel or hostel in Tromsø before your hike, ask them if you can store your luggage there.  I've done this several times in several countries and I've never been charged for it.  Most recently I did so at a youth hostel in Trondheim, Norway.  A friend has also done so at a hotel in Dombås even though he wasn't staying there at all (I think he did pay for it).

Just make sure the reception is open when you return to pick up your luggage!

Comment: I'm staying the first night in a hostel and I planned to ask there (in advance). I just wanted to know if there would be a convenient alternative if I get declined.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, Norway is an expensive country so you should be prepared to pay expensive prices.

The cheapest is in the Jekta shopping centre, not far from the airport. The charge is 10NOK for 24 hours and are **coin-operated**.

The opening hours are as follows:

> Monday – Friday:       10am – 9pm (10.00 – 21.00)
> Saturday:                    10am – 6pm (10.00 – 18.00)

([Website](https://www.visittromso.no/en/Luggage_storage))

Or alternatively as suggested by @gerrit you can ask your hotel/accommodation to store your luggage. From online I see that a lot of people asked for them to do so and they were more than happy to, just check the opening times.

If the Jekta shopping centre no longer has those facilities the Rica Ishavshotel has graciously allowed non guests to store their luggage there" but you may wish to check with them.

Or try the Nerstranda shopping centre for 50 NOK a day, opening hours:

> Mon-Fri 9am – 8pm (09.00-20.00)
> Sat 10am – 6pm (10.00-18.00).

These are **coin operated**.

In the worst case you will have to pay 60 NOK.

Comment: @GittingGud Sorry autocorrect, I mean jekta shopping centre  https://www.visittromso.no/en/Luggage_storage

Comment: I've found the same page you found but I think the information may be outdated as the [current floor plan](https://jekta.no/en/plan-overview/) of the mall doesn't show any storage lockers.

Comment: @GittingGud edited answer